# How to read binary 32-bit fixed-point number in Java

Tags: java, ruby

I need to read Adobe's signed 32-bit fixed-point number, with 8 bits for the integer part followed by 24 bits for the fractional part.  This is a "path point", as defined in [Adobe Photoshop File Formats Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/).

This is how I'd do it in Ruby, but I need to do it in Java.

```rb
  read(1).unpack('c*')[0].to_f +
    (read(3).unpack('B*')[0].to_i(2).to_f / (2 ** 24)).to_f
```

Comment: I have no idea what that is. Are you asking how to get the first 8 and the last 24 bits of an `int`?

Comment: basically I am trying to read "Path points" from http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/

Comment: Unclear what he's asking?  Seriously?  If it were unclear what the OP is asking, there wouldn't be two detailed answers here.  This close reason is a joke.  Voting to re-open.

Comment: @DavidWallace I was just thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Based on some discussion in the comments of David Wallace's answer, there is a significantly faster way to compute the correct `double`.

Probably the very fastest way to convert it is like this:

```
double intFixedPoint24ToDouble(int bits){
    return ((double) bits) / 1<<24;
}
```

The *reason* that this is faster is because of the way double-precision floating point arithmatic works. In this case, the above sequence can be converted to some extremely simple additions and bit shifting. When this gets run, the actual steps it takes look like this:

1. Convert an `int` (`bits`) to a `double` (done on FPU, usually). This is quite fast.
2. Subtract `0x00180000` from the upper 32 bits of that result. This is extremely fast.

A very similar optimization can be applied whenever you multiply or divide any floating point number by any compile-time constant integer that is a power of two.

This compiler optimization does not apply if you are instead dividing by a `double`, or if you divide by a non-compile-time-constant expression (any expression involving anything other than `final` compile-time-constant variables, literal numbers, or operators). In that case, it must be performed as a double-precision floating-point division, which is probably the *slowest single operation*, except for block transfers and advanced mathematical functions.

However, as you can see, `1<<24` is a compile-time constant power of two, and so the optimization *does* apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Read your bytes into an `int` (which is always 32 bits in Java), then use this.  You need `double`, not `float`, because single precision floating point won't necessarily be long enough to hold your 32 bit fixed point number.

```
double toFixedPoint(int bytes){
    return bytes / Math.pow(2, 24);
}
```

If speed is a concern, then work out `Math.pow(2,24)` outside of this method and store it.

Comment: If speed is a concern, just write `1<<24`, which is a compile-time constant.

Comment: @AJMansfield Yeah, but you need a `double` not an `int`, or the division doesn't work.  So you'd have to convert it anyway.

Comment: `((double) 1<<24)` is also a compile-time constant. Or, you can use `bytes * Double.longBitsToDouble(0x3E70000000000000L)`, which is far faster than division or `Math.pow(anything, anything)`.

Comment: OK, but if you're only going to evaluate it once (which will be the case if you move the call outside of the method), then readability is far more important than shaving off a few nanoseconds.  `Math.pow(2,24)` is easy to read and understand.  `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x3E70000000000000L)` less so.

Comment: firstly, thank you guys.

secondly I am trying to read "Path points" from http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/

will the above code work correctly for that, i am on windows

Comment: Even if you put it in a `final` constant outside the method, the problem is that you still have a _division by a `double`_ operation. By writing it as `((double) bytes) / 1<<24`, you are doing a _cast to double and subtract 24 from the exponent_ operation.

Comment: And the primary reason to be using fixed point numbers for _anything_ is so you can process a lot of data quickly.

Comment: Wow, the substitution of "exponent subtraction" for actual division is a really sophisticated optimisation.  I'm happy to admit that I knew nothing about that.  I feel it might be better if you post your own answer; that particular revelation deserves better than to be buried deep in a comment under MY answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ok, I just wrote up the solution in my own answer, and explained exactly how the optimization works.